# ServletFileUpload itemIterator has no elements

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a web-application with file uploading, using this code:

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    //some actions
}
```

In standalone application, deployed on tomcat all works fine. But when i import this controllers in another web-application as a jar, iterator has no items. `request.getParameterMap();` is not empty, but it has no information about file.

Comment: Make sure the form's tag is correct - the method is POST and the enctype is multipart/form-data

Comment: The tag and method is correct - nothing changed in code, just gone from standalone app to an imported library. Requests going to server is the same (as says chrome console).